# Where can I get knowledge on transient mode boost converter for SMPS?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, boost

I am working on boost converters for switching mode power supply . How can I get knowledge on transient mode boost converter ? 
As I know there are different topologies named CCM , DCM and TM which means Transient Mode .

Thanks

Comment: CCM, DCM, and TM are not different topologies, rather, they are different modes of operation for a switching power supply controller. Buck/boost/flyback/SEPIC are examples of different topologies.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I get knowledge on transient mode boost converter

I believe you mean *burst* mode operation. This is when the regulator is so lightly loaded that the output voltage starts to drift above the upper limit of acceptable operation. This happens because minimum value of pulse width that the circuit can produce still carries enough energy to the output to exceed the energy that would be converted to heat by the load hence, the output voltage rises too high.

When this happens the only resort is to cease switching for several cycles: -

[image]

The impact of this is that the p-p ripple on the output is significantly increased.

Comment: Is this also called pulse slipping operation?

Comment: @anhnha I believe it is.